# Logical Replication of table with many fields, functions and indexes

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-performance, postgresql-12, logical-replication

I have a table with 16 millions rows that needs to be replicated. The table has a total of 115 columns. Within those, there are 50 varchars columns and primary key with uuid that has 36 chars. There are 15 indexes,some dependencies and **some functions**.

The step I took :

- make a copy of the table to the subscriber. So it doesn't have to go through the initialization phase of replication process.
- create `replica identity : default`
- create publication
- create subscription : `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION try1 CONNECTION 'host=10.100.9.40 port=5432 user=jhon password=gr3AT dbname=db_profile_20210714' PUBLICATION pub_try1 with (copy_data = false);`

No data get sent to the subscriber.
I check the wall difference on the Publisher at 3 seconds interval using: `SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), replay_lsn) FROM pg_stat_replication`  .
The result of running it 3 times are : 10000, 5000 and 0. It cycles again over time, following more or less similar pattern.

Here my settings of the database :

name                     |setting   |unit
-------------------------+----------+----

archive_command          |(disabled)|
archive_mode             |off       |
archive_timeout          |0         |s
hot_standby              |on        |
max_replication_slots    |10        |
max_wal_senders          |5         |
max_wal_size             |8192      |MB
min_wal_size             |2048      |MB
synchronous_standby_names|*         |
wal_level                |logical   |
wal_log_hints            |off       |
wal_sender_timeout       |60000     |ms

I tried another replications of the same table with less data (5000 data and empty) on the Publisher, with the same number of columns and indexes etc **but without functions**. I create 2 subscription with option `copy_data : false` and `copy_data : true`. Then I enter some data into the table using query on the Publisher : `INSERT INTO table_publisher INTO SELECT * FROM table`. both working normally, data get inserted into the subscriber.

Questions :

1. Does size matters in replication ? I don't think so
2. The table is actually got its data from an app. Does it matter if the table got data from apps ?
3. Does Functions block the replication ?
4. How can I make this replication work ?

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean for a table to *have* a function?

Comment: Function, like Store Procedure.

Comment: I tried it with empty table on the Subscriber. It works... But now I have to insert manually the remaining records to the Subscriber.

Comment: What makes the replication not working ? I don't see any duplication on the Subscriber table. `COUNT (ID)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT())` give out the same result

Comment: Stored procedures don't belong to tables.

Comment: Consider looking in the log file on the subscribing end.